# catch not being triggered even though there is error in try

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, try-catch

I have a `$.getJSON()` call in my try that is throwing an error, but the catch is not being triggered. Nothing is happening. Just the error in the console.

Why is this?

What I'm trying to do is do something if the JSON is loaded and do something else if there is a failure or error in the request.

Here is my code:

```
try{
    $.getJSON('https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/search?query=&filter=(all+type%3A%22nominated%20works+exhibited_at%3A%222012%20grammy%27s%22)&indent=true', function(searchJSON){
        alert('sucesss!');
    });
}
catch(e){
    alert('failure: '+e);
}
```

Here is a link to a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/sgeg56c3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your callback function is asynchronous, while your try / catch block is synchronous. By the time your async callback has finished, the try / catch block may have already finished.

Since exceptions are handled synchronously, you'll need to use a different method for error handling.

I recommend reading [Asynchronous Error Handling in Javascript](http://ruben.verborgh.org/blog/2012/12/31/asynchronous-error-handling-in-javascript/)